# getline not declared in this scope despite importing stdio

Tags: c, getline, stdio

I need to use `getline()` in C, but when i write:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  char *line;
  getline(&line, NULL, stdin);
  free(line);

  return (0);
}
```

compiler writes `error: getline was not declared in this scope` what can i do? Isn't getline is delared in `stdio.h`? I never had this kind of problem before.

I use GCC GNU Compiler.

Comment: Isnt getline from std? try `std::getline`. IN addition, getline is declared in `#include <string>`.

Comment: error: getline is not a member of std

Comment: @wendelbsilva; Header for `getline` is `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: @wendelbsilva It's a C question not C++.

Comment: @user9000 You are right.. its a C question. The getline I was talking about is the C++ one (from stdc++).

Comment: I see your question has been edited several times. The code you have now compiles for me without error, using `gcc` with no additional options. BTW, if `std::getline` causes an error "getline is not a member of std", then you're compiling your code as C++. Use a C compiler to compile C. (Use `gcc`, not `g++`, and name your source file with a `.c` suffix.)

Comment: What operating system are you using? `getline` is provided by the runtime library, not by the compiler; gcc is just the compiler, and it will use the native runtime library for your system (glibc on Linux, other library implementations elsewhere).

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` to use this function, either define it before the inclusion of `stdio.h` or pass it to the compile as `-D_GNU_SOURCE` since this is a GNU extension function.

Another possible cause is that your GLIBC does not have this function, so either try:

- grepping for it in `/usr/include/stdio.h`
- Test for `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700` like the manual page says (after including `features.h`)

The following implementation **may** work (Un-tested):

```
#define INTIAIL_SIZE 100
size_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
{
    char c;
    size_t read = 0;
    char *tmp;

    if (!*lineptr) {
        if (!n)
            *n = INTIAIL_SIZE;

        tmp = malloc(*n);
        *lineptr = tmp;
    } else
        tmp = *lineptr;

    while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != '\n') {
        *tmp++ = c;

        if (++read >= *n) {
            char *r = realloc(tmp, *n * 2);
            if (!r) {
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return -1;
            } else
                tmp = r;
        }
    }

    *n = read;
    return read;
}
```

Errors you currently have:

- You're not freeing `line` after you've used it
- You're not passing `line` by reference, since the function prototype is: `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);` hence `char **lineptr`

Comment: Free line after using it: OK, but freeing some memory doesn't resovle the problem that the function isnt declared.

Comment: including features.h also gives compile error: no such file or directory

Comment: Also, `free` is defined in `stdlib.h` so make sure to include that.

Comment: what is greeping for the function?

Comment: Searching for it, if you're on a Linux system use this `grep "getline" /usr/include/stdio.h`

Comment: You can try the implementation I wrote, it might work as getline would, it's untested though.

Comment: @kajacx What kind of system are you on ? Your example, as it stands now, compiles on a glibc based linux platform. Other platforms might need other concerns, if they have the getline() function at all.