# Program that reads "n" lines from the user and writes it to a text file in C

Tags: c

I was asked to write a program that asks an integer from the user which represents that number of sentences that the user will write to the text file. Then the user will write those sentences. My problem with the my code below is that it only reads the first sentence that i;ve input and it will be written to the text file. what's wrong with it? 
NOTE: the getline() won't work for some reason.keep on saying that "it was not declared on this scope". I'm using DEV-C btw.

```
main(){

    int n;
    char line[100];
    FILE *in_file;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    in_file = fopen("lines.txt","w");

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        gets(line);
        fprintf(in_file,"%s",line); 
    }

    fclose(in_file);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Why do you think "NOTE: the getline() won't work for some reason" is *not* the problem, then?

Comment: well, getline() is under stdio.h, right? or do i have to define it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write multiple lines of text to a text file in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568000/how-to-write-multiple-lines-of-text-to-a-text-file-in-c)

Comment: well no one seems to be replying to my previous question, so i made a new one. i'm still having problems with it though

Comment: You shold have *edited* your original question, instead of writing an "answer" (and now it's a mess; better delete it). Anyhow: here is your `getline` problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335695/getline-not-declared-in-this-scope-despite-importing-stdio

Answer (score 2):

1) Instead of `gets()` you should always use `fgets()`.

If you compile the code with `gets()` you'll get the following warning on GCC:

> /tmp/ccq8G5WV.o: In function `main':
>
> writelines.c:(.text+0x62): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.

2) After you enter number of lines to write in `lines.txt` i.e `scanf("%d",&n);` you need to remove `\n` from the input stream.

Try this example:

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int n, i, c;
    char line[100];
    FILE *in_file;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    //Remove \n from input stream
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );

    in_file = fopen("lines.txt","w");

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fgets(line, 100, stdin);
        fprintf(in_file,"%s",line); 
    }

    fclose(in_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @SabelJimenez if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is very ok. scanf just read the characters before \n and leave out the \n in the stream buffer. You should remove it, otherwise it will count as one line. Besides, fprintf should add \n for very line because gets() also remove \n from your input. If not, all lines will concantenate together and display one line.  I just combine the above answer and you original code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int n;
    int i;
    char c;
    char line[100];
    FILE *in_file;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF )
        ;

    in_file = fopen("lines.txt","w");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        gets(line);
        fprintf(in_file,"%s\n",line); 
    }   

    fclose(in_file);
}
```

Comment: You should not use `gets()`, it is deprecated.

Comment: @1336087: Yes, the gets() should be replaced by the more safe function fgets().